# Why maps package adding straight lines in North America using mercator projection in r?

Tags: r, mercator

Why is this code creating a bunch of lines crossing the map?

```
map(database = "world", 
    proj="mercator",
    fill=FALSE,
    bg="white",
    resolution=0)
```

[image]

How can I remove it without changing the projection?

```
map(database = "world", 
    proj="albers",param=c(39, 45), 
    fill=FALSE,
    bg="white",
    resolution=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your polygons (Russia, Aleutians) are crossing the antimeridian (-180W/E) and R isn't able to break them. You need to open the shapefile in QGIS or other GIS and edit the polygons so they break at +/-180.

Comment: I don't know where that shape file is stored. Maybe I'll try another map of function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `wrap` argument of the `map` function to fix the issue.

```
map(database = "world", 
   proj="mercator",
   fill=FALSE,
   bg="white", 
   wrap =TRUE,
   resolution=0)
```

Comment: Nice! But it's not working with the `proj="albers",param=c(39, 45)` which is a area-preserving projection.